# css :hover on ul li, don't do that hover on ul li.dont-hover but not with override

Tags: css, hover

I am wondering if the following is possible, couldn't find it while searching for it the last half hour so here it is.

i got a unordered list

```
<ul>
 <li class="head">Day 1</li>
 <li>10:00</li>
 <li>12:00</li>
 <li class="head">day 2</li>
 <li>10:00</li>
 <li>14:00</li>
</ul>

<style>
ul li.head {
 background-color:green;
}
ul li:hover {
 background-color:red;
}
</style>
```

Now, if you hover over the li.head it also gets a red backgound.

**So my question is, is there something like**

```
<style>
ul li.head {
 background-color:green;
}
ul li:hover !for li.head {
 background-color:red;
}
</style>
```

I just want to know if there is something like this in css and I am not looking for other solutions, that is not my point.

To make it clear, I do not want to override it like

```
<style>
ul li.head {
 background-color:green;
}
ul li:hover {
 background-color:red;
}
ul li.head:hover {
 background-color:green;
}
</style>
```

Nor do I want

```
<style>
ul li:hover {
 background-color:red;
}
ul li.head {
 background-color:green;
}
</style>
```

I just want to know if there is anything like it in css.

note: You might think why if you can simply override it with this code, but I really simplified this as a example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this:-

No need to override. you can specify `:not()` to filter unwanted ones out.

#### [Sample Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cWegk/)

```
ul li:not(.head):hover {
 background-color:red;
}
```

Not supported below IE9 though.

[Ref :not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:not)

Comment: this will work as long as you don't care about IE8 and below.

Comment: sorry just deleted my answer because he didn't want an override, he was asking the question of is it possible. this answer is what he was looking for.